# Cordova/PhoneGap Android 4.4.2 Viewport Ignored

Tags: cordova

I just updated my phone to Android 4.4.2 and now my Cordova/PhoneGap app has started to look really strange. Everything is really big! It looks like the Viewport meta tag is being ignored.

I've looked around for a solution but I can't find any. Has anyone else experienced this problem?